# define a custom Compare for multiset

Tags: c++, function, lambda, stl, decltype

```
function<bool(const pair<int, int>&, const pair<int, int>&)> cmp = [](const pair<int, int> & left, const pair<int, int> & right){if(left > right) return true;};

//multiset<pair<int, int>, function<bool(const pair<int, int>&, const pair<int, int>&)> mt(cmp);
multiset<pair<int, int>, decltype(cmp)> mt1(cmp);

cout<<typeid(decltype(cmp)).name()<<endl<<typeid(cmp).name()<<endl;
```

the comment code(`mt`) will make an error whereas the line below(`mt1`) won't.

I tried to `cout` the name of two type and they are the same.

Besides, I also tried like this:

```
multiset<pair<int, int>, const function<bool(const pair<int, int>&, const pair<int, int>&) &> mt(cmp);
```

or

```
multiset<pair<int, int>, function<bool(const pair<int, int>&, const pair<int, int>&) &> mt(cmp);
```

All of them don't work.

So what is the type of the second argument exactly? If I don't use `decltype`, how can I declare it?

Comment: [Not proved](https://ideone.com/rXwfME)

Comment: Maybe you missed a `>`, check again

Comment: Basic, machine-generated compiler warnings can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: `std::multiset<std::pair<int, int>, std::greater<>>` should do your example job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully at your code, you lost a `>`.

```
multiset<pair<int, int>, function<bool(const pair<int, int>&, const pair<int, int>&)>> mt(cmp);
//                                                                                   ~
```

Using `decltype` should be a good idea.

BTW: You should return something when `if` returns `false` in lambda. Or just `return left > right;`.

Answer (score 0):

These three multisets exhibit equivalent ordering behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

auto cmp = [](const pair<int, int> & left, 
              const pair<int, int> & right)
{
  return left > right;
};

multiset<pair<int, int>, decltype(cmp)> mt1(cmp);
multiset<pair<int, int>, std::greater<>> mt2;
multiset<pair<int, int>, std::function<bool(const pair<int, int>&, const pair<int, int>&)>> mt3(cmp);

int main()
{
  mt1.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));
  mt2.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));
  mt3.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));
}
```

Of the three, I would strongly advise choosing this one:

```
multiset<pair<int, int>, std::greater<>> mt2;
```

Comment: `multiset<pair<int, int>, std::greater<>> mt2;` looks great but it doesn't work. I tried also `std::greater<pair<int, int>>` but doesn't work either.

Comment: can you define "doesn't work?" compiles and functions perfectly for me. Which compiler? Have you enabled c++11?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php    I tried here and it said: `template argument 2 is invalid`. But I tried with my local compilier and it works well. So maybe it's the problem of this online compiler.

Comment: @Thomas yes it looks as if they have an ancient version of the standard library. Sloppy...

Comment: hmm...I thought it was under c++11... Anyway, thanks for you help.